# Why calling function with function pointer does not guarantee the calling order with printf in C

Tags: c, pointers

While I studying about C language, there is some strange situation about array of function pointer.
This is a sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int n) {
        printf("foo: %d\n", n);
        return 0;
}

int bar(int n) {
        printf("bar: %d\n", n);
        return 1;
}

int main() {
        int (*p[2])(int) = { foo, bar };
        printf("%d %d\n", p[0](10), p[1](20));
        return 0;
}
```

Intuitively, function foo called first and function bar called second, but it does not.

What I expect as a result,

```
foo: 10
bar: 20
0 1
```

However, actual output is

```
bar: 20
foo: 10
0 1
```

To analyze the result, I create the assembly file using gcc. In main function, the assembly code looks like below.

```
main:
    # codes ...
    leaq  foo(%rip), %rax
    movq  %rax, -48(%rbp)  ; p[0] = foo;
    leaq  bar(%rip), %rax
    movq  %rax, -40(%rbp)  ; p[1] = bar;
    
    movq  -40(%rbp), %rax
    movl  $10, %edi
    call  *%rax            ; p[1](10);

    movq  -48(%rbp), %rax
    movl  $20, %rdi
    call  *%rax            ; p[0](20);
    # codes ...
```

Why gcc compiles bar(p[1]) first and foo(p[2])? Why it does not work intuitively?

Comment: The C standard should not require argument evaluations to be sequenced for at least two reasons. (a) Some systems might require arguments to be pushed on the stack left-to-right while others might require arguments to be pushed onto the stack right-to-left. Requiring one order or the other would make it more difficult to prepare arguments on the other kind of system, imposing an unnecessary performance penalty on it.

Comment: (b) Arguments may be compound expressions that contain common subexpressions or that require time to compute. Since we want programs to perform well, we want compilers to optimize, and there can be opportunities for optimizing by computing some common part of several arguments, then start working on one argument, then finish another argument while the earlier one is finishing its computing (modern processors execute many instructions in parallel), and then finish the earlier argument. Imposing argument evaluation order would preclude these optimizations.

Comment: The same thing happens if you call `foo` and `bar` directly, without all the function pointer stuff